# Maven dependency not found InteliJ Ultimate 2020

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I found similar problems raised but proposed solutions are not working for me.
What I am trying to is to automatically download dependencies in my maven project using pom.xml

My pom looks like:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RELASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And i have no idea why I am getting: **Dependency 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.0.RELASE' not found**

I tried to do `mvn clean install`

*[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.0.RELASE/spring-context-5.1.0.RELASE.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.0.RELASE is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.0.RELASE/spring-context-5.1.0.RELASE.jar*

**so the the jar is downloaded to my local repository**  but i get:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dependencies: Could not resolve dependencies for project pl.javastart:dependencies:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.0.RELASE in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

This is a maven project and I am using InteliJ Ultimate 2020, maven 3.6.3

In Maven settings i have checked automatic download options

[image: For maven importing checked automatic download]

**EDIT:**
Yes, a typo... I will leave the question, it will be funny for me some day in the future.

Any ideas how to force InteliJ / maven to automatically download dependencies after saving pom.xml instead of `mvn install`  or clicking project > maven > Reimport?

Comment: Typo `RELASE` for `RELEASE`?

Answer (score 1):

Theres a typ0

```
    <version>5.1.0.RELASE</version> // incorrect
    <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>  // correct
```